# Subquery returns more than 1 row issues with group by

Tags: mysql

Please help resolve what is wrong with my query below I get "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
select
count(*) NONGENACC,  AFFILIATE,
(SELECT COUNT(ACCOUNTNO) from realdb.tbl_logs GROUP BY AFFILIATE )AS ALLACCS
FROM  realdb.tbl_logs
where LASTDATE <> CURDATE() group by AFFILIATE
```

it returns the below when i take the GROUP BY from the sub query which is not what i want in the allacs field. Kindly help...

```
NONGENACC AFFILIATE      ALLACCS 
1         ECOCBFBF        1481 
2         ECOCBIBI        1481 
13        ECOCBJBJ        1481 
11        ECOCCDKI        1481 
3         ECOCCFCF        1481
```

Comment: Hi, can you create [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and show us what result you expect to get from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `GROUP BY AFFILIATE` from subquery.
So you final query will look like this:

```
select
count(*) NONGENACC,  AFFILIATE,
(SELECT COUNT(ACCOUNTNO) from realdb.tbl_logs)AS ALLACCS
FROM  realdb.tbl_logs
where LASTDATE <> CURDATE() group by AFFILIATE
```

Comment: he will get the same value **(SELECT COUNT(ACCOUNTNO) from realdb.tbl_logs)** for all rows

Comment: Yes, but subquery will ruturn only one row, instead 5

Comment: that doesn't have a much sans becouse that will count all ACCOUNTNO in table.. he should remove compleatly subquery and have COUNT(ACCOUNTNO) AS ALLACCS that might work... but if he don't provide expected result we can't know for sure what he should do.. GL

Comment: Thank you all I expect the results to be something like this:NONGENACC AFFILIATE      ALLACCS
​1         ECOCBFBF       37
2         ECOCBIBI        28
13        ECOCBJBJ        72
11        ECOCCDKI        38
3         ECOCCFCF        56 ​

Comment: @Gladys please edit your question and there add that here we can't see a lot :)

Comment: ok Aleks thank u. Today is my first time here trying  to find my way around here :)

Comment: @Gladys no problem :) we just try to help but sometimes we need some more information so we can do that... under your question should be three options share, edit, flag click on edit and you should be able to add new information and improve your question...

Answer (score 0):

okay thank you all for your sugestions. I got a way of getting the result I wanted by using the query below instead:

```
  SELECT AFFILIATE, 'TotalAccounts', count(accountno)
  FROM realdb.tbl_logs
  GROUP BY AFFILIATE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AFFILIATE, 'MissingAccount', count(accountno)
  FROM realdb.tbl_logs
  WHERE LASTDATE <> CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY AFFILIATE 
  ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```